# Кнопка для выдвижения DrawerLayout

Tags: java, android

Собственно проблема в следующем, экспериментирую с DrawerLayout. XML представление имеет следуюший вид:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Сразу первый вопрос не совсем по проблеме, Я правильно понимаю что представление DrawerLayout должно всегда состоять из двух элементов (которые впрочем внутри себя могут включать другие элементы) и нижний элемент отвечает за то, что находится на выезжающий панели а верхний то что на экране?

И есть сам класс активности которая работает с этой активностью:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    mTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, mTitles));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DraweItemClickListener());

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer){
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }


    };

    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

}
```

Сама панель при свапе пальцем выезжает, но я не понимаю как сделать кнопку в верхнем левом углу что бы по нажатию на нее панель выезжала или пряталась. И это основной вопрос.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32614629/3212712) вам надо так делать:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

if (actionBar != null)
{
   actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
   mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.hello_world, R.string.hello_world)
   {

      public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
      {
         supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
         //drawerOpened = false;
      }

      public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
      {
         supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
         //drawerOpened = true;
      }
   };
   mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
   drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
   mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

Плюс переопределить в актвити методы в которых состояние гамбургера надо синхронизировать:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Comment: Сделал, не работает. У меня подозрения сейчас возникло в голове что это как то связано со стилями...

Comment: Все разобрался. у меня не вызывался этот метод - setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); Спасибо Вам, заметил это!